# Error al compilar proyecto en Angular 5

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

estoy tratando de obtener un JSON mediante POST con angular, pero me sale el siguiente error.

```
   Error: Unexpected value 'AppComponent' declared by the module 'AppModule'. Please add a @Pipe/@Directive/@Component annotation.
```

La verdad no se que pueda ser, debe de ser algo sencillo, o algún error por algún cambio en la versión.

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';


//importar servicio

import { PostService } from './post.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  providers: [PostService]
});

export class AppComponent {


  title : string;

  nombre : string;
  email : string;


  //email = "correo";

  //array
  hobbies : string[];

  mostradoHB : boolean;



constructor(private variablePostService:PostService) {

  this.variablePostService.obtenerPost().subscribe(post=> {

    console.log(post);

  });



  this.title = 'Aplicacion con angular';
  this.email = "micorreo";
  this.nombre = 'Brian';

  this.hobbies = ['Correr','Leer', 'Ver series'];


  this.mostradoHB = true;

}//constructor

/*

toggleHobbies(){

  this.mostradoHB = !this.mostradoHB;

}


nuevoHobbie(dato){

  this.hobbies.push(dato.value);
  dato.value = '';
  //return false;

}

}

*/

}//clase
```

app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http'; 

//aqui se cargan todos los componentes creados
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Elimina el punto y coma `;` que tienes en la declaracion de la anotacion `@Component` de `AppComponent` que esta causando el error:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  providers: [PostService]
}); <--- elimina este punto y coma

export class AppComponent
```

Comment: Vale muchas gracias @Einer al parecer los puntos y comas son un lio en typeScript luego que regresas de Java. Faltaban otros puntos y comas por ahi.
Un saludo